# How can I train my ear?

Tags: guitar, piano, ear-training, self-learning

So, months ago I started to study how to play guitar and piano, I already got to play some songs, but I feel very awkward playing something by ear. Therefore, i'd like some tips on where I have to start and how could I do this without that bad feeling that "I can't do that".

Comment: You can evaluate yourself if you record yourself with midi or microphone.

Comment: @Emil Indeed, ty

Comment: If/when I finish my program that tells you if you are out of tune relative to a midi file based on microphone input I can try to share it. But it was a bit hard to implement the pitch detection so I don't have anything yet.